# Why do functional analysts want their spaces to be complete?

Tags: functional-analysis, soft-question, hilbert-spaces, motivation

Why is one in functional analysis only investigating complete spaces (like Banach or Hilbert spaces)? I heard someone saying that analysts in general like to work with limits, which makes sense. But what would be more satisfying is to see a concrete situation in the theory where completeness is essential. Also, why is it essential in the applications to differential equations?

And anyways: Is there not much to say about non-complete normed spaces? Have people investigated them?

Comment: Differential equations are strongly associated with fixed point iterations, completeness is desirable to know that a sequence is converging to a point in the space of relevance. One can always create a completion of a space (typically dealing with equivalence classes, which is messy), so for many applications there is no real loss in assumption of completeness.

Comment: Why is nobody answering?

Comment: @copper.hat Thanks! That's a nice first idea. :-)